# Installing vc++ 2013 x86 from MSI file does not work

Tags: c++, windows-installer, installation, redistributable

I fetched the extracted msi & cab files for the runtime installation but for some reason it does not work. It says "Gathering required information" and then just disappears. I took the arguments from the original install logs (MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1") and I tested on XP and windows 7

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other alternative is to make use of merge modules to install the VC runtimes, instead of having to use a bootstrapper. Again, it depends on what you want the runtimes for. If they are required for any of the custom action dll's that make up your msi package, then bootstrapping is the only option you have. However, if they are required for your product, then a merge module can very well serve your pupose.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Installer has a mutex that generally prevents one MSI from installing another MSI.  You need a bootstrapper / chainer to install the packages in serial.